# Changes made in Splash screen are not getting reflected

Tags: android, flutter, splash-screen

I was recently trying to add a splash screen to my android app that I am trying to develop. But no matter what changes I make changes are not getting reflected. I am new to flutter to I am including a lot of code. Here is the code -

**values>colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="background_color">#FFCC00</color>
</resources>
```

**drawable>>launch_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/background_color" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <!-- <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/welcome" />
    </item> -->
</layer-list>
```

I am using flutter channel 'master' as Android Studio 4.1.2 is not supported in channel 'stable'

Please inform me if any other code is required. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try flutter clean then redo all the steps to generate all the file on splash screen

Comment: @Reign It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot of stuff. Wasted nearly 14 hours, to realize that Android Studio 4.1.2, has some sort of problem with flutter doctor as of 12/2/2021. So I switched back to Android Studio 4.0 and re-installed the flutter SDK. This solved the problem for me. As far as, I am aware of the issue, it was due to different unsupported versions of Android Studio and Flutter. Maybe in the future, smart guys at google sort this out :)

Answer (score 0):

Just want to drop this here for those who may have this issue with React Native. What solved it for me was slightly renaming the splash screen file inside my assets folder. It was **splash.png**, after I made changes to it and overrode the file, the old splash screen kept showing.

Reloading, restarting the server, clearing cache, none solved it.

When I finally renamed the file to **splashscreen.png** and reload. Viola!